# Element of the set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the set $A=\lbrace 1,2,3,4\rbrace$, list all the elements of the set:
$$\lbrace (a, n) \in A × \mathbb N: a = n\rbrace$$

Do I substitute each of the elements in to $a$?

Comment: Is $N$ the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: yes indeed it is the natural numbers

Comment: The notation is peculiar (regarding your use of colon and semicolon). More standard notation would be $$\{(a,n)\in A\times\mathbb N:a=n\}.$$

Comment: @MPW $A\subset \mathbb N$ is the case here, but is not *presumed* for your notation - if $A\cap \mathbb N=\emptyset$ for example, fine, this is the empty set

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, I didn't notice that $A$ was explicitly defined when I was writing my answer. I've corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)$$

Comment: can you please explain it to me why thats is?

Comment: By definition you have that if $x \in A\times \mathbb{N}$ then $x = (a,n)$ such that $a \in A$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As the condition $a = n$ was set we have the elements above.

Comment: hey i appreaciate your help this helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help.